# Matplotlib frameon issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried changing the default settings for figure frames in the `rcsetup.py` file to have the figure frame off by default. Before I changed anything, whenever I'd use 
`plt.figure(frameon=False)` 
the frame would disappear, but after changing the 'figure.frameon' entry in the rcsetup.py file to False, the frame just stays on no matter what I do. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing matplotlib, changing the default setting back to True, but the figure frame just won't go away. I have tried changing some of the other default settings, but they all do what I tell them to.

How can I change the default settings back to normal again? Everything described above was done on the latest version of `matplotlib`.

Comment: What is "the rcsetup.py file"? What changes do you make to it?

Comment: It's the file where you can change the rcParams dictionary. For the figure frame, the only thing I changed was the `'figure.frameon'` entry to False. After that when I ran my program the whole figure had a white background (normally it would be gray around the axes when I used `fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)`). When I changed the `'figure.frameon'` entry to True again the figure would still remain white no matter what I did to it or wherever I'd try to turn off the frame (in the script itself, in the `rcparams.py` file, etc).

Comment: Hold on, where is that file? Are you changing the source code of matplotlib?

Comment: It's in the matplotlib source folder.

Comment: Wow, ok. So if you change anything inside the matplotlib source, probably just anything can happen. Just don't do that. Never. I hope you have a backup, else you need to reinstall matplotlib.

Comment: There is a tutorial about [customizing matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html). Please read it and if something is unclear ask about that.